# Quantization distortion in x-axis of GLMakie plot. Why?

Tags: julia, makie.jl

I create a simple plot using `GLMakie`:

```
GLMakie.scatter( range((-3e-9+1e-3)..(3e-9+1e-3),100), range(1..100,100) )
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Looks like the x-axis is heavily quantized. The `Plots` package handles the same command just fine:

```
Plots.scatter( range((-3e-9+1e-3)..(3e-9+1e-3),100), range(1..100,100) )
```

[image]

`GLMakie` can also handle the same plot if the x range is centered on 0:

```
GLMakie.scatter( range((-5e-9)..(5e-9),100), range(1..100,100) )
```

[image]

Why is this happening?  Does `GLMakie` use a smaller float for speed?  Can I do anything to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does GLMakie use a smaller float for speed?

Yes it does. OpenGL commonly uses 32 bit floats and Makie has been built with Float32 as a result. Right now you'd have normalize your data and adjust ticks manually to fix this. See https://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/examples/layoutables/axis/index.html#modifying_ticks

There are also a bunch of issues regarding this on github, for example https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl/issues/1373.

Comment: That's bad! I wonder if the situation has changed recently?